# visual studio crash after update 2?

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2013, fxcop

using vs2013 i had no problem so far with fxcop

new 'feature': devenv crashes after i select an entry in the code analysis sidebar (fxcop)

eventlog tells me:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.SdkUiUtilities.OpenDocumentInCurrentScope(System.IServiceProvider, System.String)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.SdkUiUtilities.OpenDocument(System.IServiceProvider, System.String, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.ViolationResult.NavigateTo(Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.ResultTextMarker, Boolean, System.String, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.ViolationResult.OnSelect(Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.AnalysisResults.SourceLocation[])
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.ViewModel.CodeAnalysisResult.DisplaySourceTrace(Boolean)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.ViewModel.CodeAnalysisResult.Select(Boolean)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.CodeAnalysisResultsControl.AnalysisResultList_SelectionChanged(System.Object, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
[...]
```

the last thing i changed afair was installing 'update 2'

extensions:

- ankhsvn
- behaviors sdk
- MS advertising pubCenter&sdk, asp.net&webtools, mvc5 scaffolding
- nuget
- productivity power tools
- relativelinenumbers (nice to have w/ vsvim)
- visual f#
- windowslib for js
- vsvim
- windows phone sdk
- xamarin shell, .android & .ios

am i the only one experiencing this issue? could someone verify fxcop working with vs update 2?

EDIT / new info:

- it seems to happen only with our custom rules - so it might not be an issue with visualstudio at all...
- just flew over the code for the custom rule - since there's no code at all to manage opening the issue i'm back to thinking it's VS's fault
- uninstalled xamarin, deactivated all extensions which let me, still crashing
- tried devenv.exe with /SafeMode switch, still crashes
- others in my team tried update 2 now, i'm the only one experiencing this issue - so i'm currently reinstalling vs2k13
- completely uninstalled/reinstalled vs2013 now, problem persists.
- tried various switches, no success with:

  - /ResetUserData
  - /ResetSettings
  - /ResetSkipPkgs
  - /ResetAddin
- repair installed windows sdk, didn't help...
- fiddled around w/ restore points - didn't help

any thoughts anyone?

Comment: What does the log file - %AppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ActivityLog.xml say?

Comment: there's not one .xml file in C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ and no 'ActivityLog.xml' in whole C:\Users\user\AppData\

Comment: Ok you may not have    /log switch for devenv.exe. You can try modifying the shortcut and retry. Also make sure AppData is not hidden.

Comment: find the log here: http://privatepaste.com/download/293a0078f8

Comment: Since I am behind a firewall, I am unable to view it right now. Do you see any error message towards the end?

Comment: there's one warning and one error, the warning's in the beginning (#37/585), the error nearly at the end (#568/585): [Warning] The CTM file is out of date and should be deleted and rebuilt, but the file 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\1033\devenv.CTM' could not be deleted. [ERROR] Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID 'Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop'

Comment: is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.0\DESKTOP SDK\...
          C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\

Comment: May be invalid registry keys are causing this issue. You could try falling back on to the restore point prior to the update?

Comment: i might try that on monday ;)